# Randomize listed products in categories in Magento

Tags: magento

I would like to randomize products listed in my categories in Magento Community Edition on a per session basis - to give the illusion of "freshness" or change in my categories rather than the same stale listings each time.

What I mean is I would like the user to see a different order of products when they visit a category on the site, but on a per session basis. So, let's say the user is visiting Category A for the first time, the user will be presented with a randomly ordered list of products belonging to that category. Now when they go and visit another category, say Category B, then go back to Category A, the listing will be as viewed earlier, not random. So the randomization takes place only once per session per category. Now when the user comes back say hours later, under a new session, the randomization would kick in again.

Is this possible? If so, any help or direction would be most appreciated.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, but you are going to run in to issues when you try to apply filter (such as sort by price low to high etc)

I think a better approach is to randomize by date so that everyone will get the same product order on a given day.

Below is pseudo code example that I use to display random product from a particular category  on the tag pages. (you could change the `$seed` to accomplish what you want)

```
public function _getProductCollection()
{

    if(is_null($this->_productCollection)) {
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($this->getCategoryId());

        $seed = $this->getCategoryId() . date("W");

        $this->_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
        Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->prepareProductCollection($this->_productCollection);
        $this->_productCollection->getSelect()->order("rand($seed)");
        $this->_productCollection->addStoreFilter();
        $this->_productCollection->addCategoryFilter($category);

        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($this->_productCollection);
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($this->_productCollection);
    }


    return $this->_productCollection;
}
```

Comment: Thank you and excuse me for the insane delay in response - your answer escaped me somehow! :S  Could you tell me which file(s) i'm supposed modify and what sections in order to get this to work? The filter function (i.e. sort by price low to high etc) is not something we use anyway, so it's not that important to us at the moment.

Comment: Take a look @ `_getProductCollection` in `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List` (/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php)

Comment: You should be able to also use an observer see   `catalog_block_product_list_collection`

Comment: I replaced the code as per your suggestion above — although it says `protected function _getProductCollection()` in the List.php file.

When I check output, we don't get an error on my end which is a good thing, but get "There are no products matching the selection.". I replaced the whole block of code within `protected function _getProductCollection()` with your code above. What could be wrong, please?

Comment: Take a look @ http://codebutter.wordpress.com/2011/06/23/magento-1-4-show-random-products-on-product-list-page/